# Allure + Jenkins + TestNG: xUnit not showing test cases in suite when run on Jenkins but shows on local

Tags: jenkins, testng, xunit, allure

The allure report generated on Jenkins does not show me the test cases but the one generated on my local machine does. Are there settings that needs to be changed? (See screenshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wut68oze2xq7s2/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Thanks

Comment: Silly mistake, I didn't click on the necessary tabs. They are not clicked by default as they are in local for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake, I didn't click on the necessary tabs. They are not clicked by default as they are in local for some reason